# In android who decides in which mode an USB device should be connected

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-framework

Am trying to understand USB framework in android . Can somebody help me with below questions?

1. When a USB accessory or a computer or a pen drive ( via OTG cable) is connected who decides which mode the phone will fall into? Is it decided in kernel?
2. I know there is a Vold module . If a USB pen drive is connected will vold receives the event or USB framework?

Comment: The hardware handling USB will usually detect a change in mode and alert the kernel.

Comment: but in kernel code I can c f_accessory , massstorage etc. So isnt it handled somewhere in the kernel

Comment: Yeah, when the hardware tells the kernel that it's time to switch to device mode or host mode, the kernel will load up the appropriate module